# Non-root user with permissions to manage multiple files

Tags: permissions, configuration

I am using the Consul Template project, which is a process that is responsible for rendering multiple template files into various locations on disk. This poses a challenge of how best to manage the permissions and ownership of the destination files without running the Consul template process as root.

For example, consul-template needs to render the contents of a template string and write it to locations such as /etc/default/. It does have the option of executing a command after rendering a template, so I can write to /tmp and then execute a `sudo mv`, but what would be a sane setting in the sudoers file to allow that?

I am building the servers with configuration management and know all of the destination files at build time, so I can change ownership of the destinations at that point, but the process also creates temporary files during rendering that are located in the destination directories which complicates things a bit.

If anyone has dealt with a similar situation of needing to grant broad write permissions to a non-root process and has a solution that they're happy with I'd appreciate some feedback. Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

So, after digging around more I discovered the Linux ACL system and was able to manage the necessary permissions via installing the `acl` package and then running `setfacl -m u:<username>:rwx /etc/default`.